# Javascript Steganography: Hiding an image inside of an image

Tags: javascript, image, decode, encode, steganography

I have been stuck on this program for a while and I am completely lost as to what is wrong and what I need to fix. I am trying to use steganography to encrypt a secret image inside of a cover image, and then decrypt the secret image. I am given part of the code and I have to implement the `encodePixel` and `decodePixel` functions, as well as the "helper functions".

When I run the program, the resulting image is completely black instead of the secret image. I do not know where my error is, and if it is in the encode or decode function, or if it is in the helper functions.

These are the functions that I have implemented:

```
/*
 * Encodes the given secret pixel into the low bits of the
 * RGB values of the given cover pixel
 * Returns the modified cover pixel
 */
function encodePixel(coverPixel, secretPixel) {

    var redBit = secretPixel[RED];
    var greenBit = secretPixel[GREEN];
    var blueBit = secretPixel[BLUE];


    if(redBit >= 128){
        setLowestBit(coverPixel[RED], 1);
    }else{
        setLowestBit(coverPixel[RED], 0);
    }
    if(blueBit >= 128){
        setLowestBit(coverPixel[BLUE], 1);
    }else{
        setLowestBit(coverPixel[BLUE], 0);
    }
    if(greenBit >= 128){
        setLowestBit(coverPixel[GREEN], 1);
    }else{
        setLowestBit(coverPixel[GREEN], 0);

    return coverPixel;
}


/*
 * Extracts the RGB values for a secret pixel from the low bits
 * of the given cover pixel
 * Returns the resulting secret pixel
 */
function decodePixel(coverPixel) {

    var secretPixel = [0, 0, 0];
    var redBit = getLowestBit(coverPixel[RED]);     
    var greenBit = getLowestBit(coverPixel[GREEN]); 
    var blueBit = getLowestBit(coverPixel[BLUE]);   

    if(redBit == 1){
        setLowestBit(secretPixel[RED], 255);
    }else{
        setLowestBit(secretPixel[RED], 0);
    }
    if(blueBit == 1){
        setLowestBit(secretPixel[BLUE], 255);
    }else{
        setLowestBit(secretPixel[BLUE], 0);
    }
    if(greenBit == 1){
        setLowestBit(secretPixel[GREEN], 255);
    }else{
        setLowestBit(secretPixel[GREEN], 0);
    }

    return secretPixel;
}



//=========HELPER FUNCTIONS==========\\

// Returns true if the given value is even, false otherwise
function isEven(value) {
    return value % 2 == 0;
}


/*
 * Given a number, return the lowest bit in the binary representation
 * of the number.
 * Returns either a 0 or a 1
 */
function getLowestBit(value) {
    if(isEven(value)){
        return 0;
    }else{
        return 1;
    }
}


/*
 * Given a number, return a new number with the same underlying bits
 * except the lowest bit is set to the given bitValue.
 */
function setLowestBit(value, bitValue) {
    if(bitValue == 0) {
        // If value is even, the lowest bit is already 0.
        if(isEven(value)) {
            return value;
        }
        // Otherwise, the lowest bit is 1. We subtract 1 to set it to 0.
        else {
            return value - 1;
        }
    }

    else {
        // If value is odd, the lowest bit is already 1
        if(!isEven(value)) {
            return value;
        }
        // Otherwise, the lowest bit is 0. We add 1 to set it to 1.
        else {
            return value + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the rest of the code, which I do not have to change.

```
//===============================CONSTANTS===========================\\

// Constants for the images
var ORIGINAL_URL = "https://codehs.com/static/img/zebra.jpg";
var SECRET_IMAGE_URL = "https://codehs.com/static/img/about/goldengate.jpg";

// Constants for pixel indices
var RED = 0;
var GREEN = 1;
var BLUE = 2;

// Constants for colors
var MAX_COLOR_VALUE = 255;
var MIN_COLOR_VALUE = 0;
var COLOR_THRESHOLD = 128;

//********************STARTER CODE BELOW******************************

// Constants for spacing
var X_GAP = 10;
var Y_GAP = 25;
var TEXT_Y_GAP = 4;
var IMAGE_WIDTH = getWidth() / 2 - X_GAP * 2;
var IMAGE_HEIGHT = getHeight() / 3 - Y_GAP * 1.1;
var IMAGE_X = 10;
var IMAGE_Y = 25;

// Image width cannot be odd, it messes up the math of the encoding
if(IMAGE_WIDTH % 2 == 1) {
    IMAGE_WIDTH -= 1;
}

// We need to wait for the image to load before modifying it
var IMAGE_LOAD_WAIT_TIME = 50;

function start() {
    // Set up original image
    var original = new WebImage(ORIGINAL_URL);
    original.setSize(IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT);
    original.setPosition(IMAGE_X, IMAGE_Y);

    // Set up secret image
    var secret = new WebImage(SECRET_IMAGE_URL);
    secret.setSize(IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT);
    secret.setPosition(IMAGE_X + original.getWidth() + X_GAP, IMAGE_Y);

    // Set up the cover image 
    // (identical to original, but will be modified to encode the secret image)
        var cover = new WebImage(ORIGINAL_URL);
    var coverX = getWidth() / 2 - IMAGE_WIDTH / 2;
    cover.setSize(IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT);
    cover.setPosition(IMAGE_X + IMAGE_WIDTH / 2, IMAGE_Y + Y_GAP + IMAGE_HEIGHT);

    // Add originals
    add(original);
    add(secret);

    // Add the cover image that will be used for encrypting the secret image
    add(cover);

    // Wait for images to load before encrypting and decrypting
    setTimeout(function(){
        encrypt(cover, secret);
        decrypt(cover);
    }, IMAGE_LOAD_WAIT_TIME);

    // Add labels for each image
    var originalLabel = new Text("Original Cover Image", "11pt Arial");
    originalLabel.setPosition(original.getX(), original.getY() - TEXT_Y_GAP);
    add(originalLabel);

    var secretLabel = new Text("Original Secret Image", "11pt Arial");
    secretLabel.setPosition(secret.getX(), secret.getY() - TEXT_Y_GAP);
    add(secretLabel);

    var coverLabel = new Text("Cover Image with Secret Image encoded inside", "11pt Arial");
    coverLabel.setPosition(getWidth() / 2 - coverLabel.getWidth() / 2, cover.getY() - TEXT_Y_GAP);
    add(coverLabel);

    var resultLabel = new Text("Resulting Secret Image decoded from Cover Image", "11pt Arial");
    resultLabel.setPosition(getWidth() / 2 - resultLabel.getWidth() / 2, cover.getY() + IMAGE_HEIGHT + Y_GAP - TEXT_Y_GAP );
    add(resultLabel);
}

/*
 * Encrypts the secret image inside of the cover image.
 * For each pixel in the cover image, the lowest bit of each
 * R, G, and B value is set to a 0 or 1 depending on the amount of
 * R, G, and B in the corresponding secret pixel.
 * If an R, G, or B value in the secret image is between 0 and 127,
 * set a 0, if it is between 128 and 255, set a 1.
 */
function encrypt(cover, secret) {

    // Make sure cover and secret are the same size.
    var width = cover.getWidth();
    var height = cover.getHeight();
    secret.setSize(width, height);

    // Loop over each pixel in the image
    for(var x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        for(var y = 0; y < height; y++) {

            // Get the pixels at this location for both images
            var coverPixel = cover.getPixel(x, y);
            var secretPixel = secret.getPixel(x, y);

            // Modify the cover pixel to encode the secret pixel
            var newCoverPixel = encodePixel(coverPixel, secretPixel);

            // Update this pixel in the cover image to have the
            // secret bit encoded
            cover.setRed(x, y, newCoverPixel[RED]);
            cover.setGreen(x, y, newCoverPixel[GREEN]);
            cover.setBlue(x, y, newCoverPixel[BLUE]);
        }
    }
}

/*
 * Decrypts a secret image from an encoded cover image.
 */
function decrypt(coverImage) {

    // secretImage will start off the same as the cover image.
    // As we loop over the coverImage to discover the secret embedded image,
    // we will update secretImage pixel by pixel
    var secretImage = new WebImage(coverImage.filename);

    // We need to add secretImage to the canvas before we can modify it
    secretImage.setSize(coverImage.getWidth(), coverImage.getHeight());
    secretImage.setPosition(coverImage.getX(), coverImage.getY() + coverImage.getHeight() + Y_GAP);
    add(secretImage);

    // Wait for secretImage to load on the canvas before we start
    // modifying its pixels.
    setTimeout(function(){
        computeSecretImage(coverImage, secretImage);
    }, IMAGE_LOAD_WAIT_TIME);
}

/*
 * Set the pixels in the image secret based on the lowest
 * bit values in the pixels of the image cover.
 */
function computeSecretImage(cover, secret) {
    // Loop over every pixel in the cover image
    for(var x = 0; x < cover.getWidth(); x++) {
        for(var y = 0; y < cover.getHeight(); y++) {
            //Get the current pixel of the cover image
            var coverPixel = cover.getPixel(x, y);

            // Compute the secretPixel from this cover pixel
            var secretPixel = decodePixel(coverPixel);

            // Update the pixel in the secret image to match the computed secret pixel
            secret.setRed(x, y, secretPixel[RED]);
            secret.setGreen(x, y, secretPixel[GREEN]);
            secret.setBlue(x, y, secretPixel[BLUE]);
        }
    }
}
```

I appreciate any help!

Comment: of course it's black, you `var secretPixel = [0, 0, 0];` and then you never change the value of `secretPixel`, and return it as the new value, for every single pixel.

Comment: bad quick fix before :p - try `coverPixel[RED] = setLowestBit(coverPixel[RED], 1)` etc

Comment: @JaromandaX  how do I do that? I tried doing `var secretPixel = [secretPixel[RED], secretPixel[GREEN], secretPixel[BLUE]];` instead and then using `secretPixel[RED] = setLowestBit(secretPixel[RED], 255);` and `secretPixel[RED] = setLowestBit(secretPixel[RED], 1);` for each of the colors respectively, but that didn't work. Now it is returning the original image instead of the secret image???

Comment: `var secretPixel = [secretPixel[RED], secretPixel[GREEN], secretPixel[BLUE]];` does NOTHING .. secretPixel ends up exactly what it was!

Comment: another issue is this `bitValue` you pass to `setPixel` ... it's one of 0, 1 or 255 - but there's no difference between 1 and 255 ... surely on decode you want to the returned value to be 0 or 255, whereas on encode you want the returned value to be the original value +/- 1?

Comment: @JaromandaX okay... then how do I change the value of the secretPixel??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you set the secretPixel to [0,0,0], then it never changes in any function calls. You return values from encodePixel and decodePixel, but the returned values are discarded

What you'd need to do is

```
function encodePixel(coverPixel, secretPixel) {
    var returnedPixel = [0,0,0];
    var redBit = secretPixel[RED];
    var greenBit = secretPixel[GREEN];
    var blueBit = secretPixel[BLUE];


    if(redBit >= 128){
        returnedPixel[RED] = setLowestBit(coverPixel[RED], 1);
    }else{
        returnedPixel[RED] = setLowestBit(coverPixel[RED], 0);
    }
    // repeat for blue/green
    //
    // then
    return returnedPixel;
}
```

and

```
function decodePixel(coverPixel) {

    var secretPixel = [0, 0, 0];
    var redBit = getLowestBit(coverPixel[RED]);     
    var greenBit = getLowestBit(coverPixel[GREEN]); 
    var blueBit = getLowestBit(coverPixel[BLUE]);   

    if(redBit == 1){
        secretPixel[RED] = 255;
    }
    // repeat for green and blue
    //
    // then
    return secretPixel;
}
```

> Bonus: your whole first snippet of code can be simplified as 2 lines:

```
const encodePixel = (coverPixel, secretPixel) => coverPixel.map((part, index) => (part & 254) | ((secretPixel[index] >> 7) & 1));
const decodePixel = coverPixel => coverPixel.map(part => (part & 1) * 255);
```

Or if ES6 frightens you, 10 lines:

```
var encodePixel = function encodePixel(coverPixel, secretPixel) {
    return coverPixel.map(function (part, index) {
        return (part & 254) | ((secretPixel[index] >> 7) & 1);
    });
};
var decodePixel = function decodePixel(coverPixel) {
    return coverPixel.map(function (part) {
        return (part & 1) * 255;
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
/* Encodes the given secret pixel into the low bits of the
 * RGB values of the given cover pixel.
 * Returns the modified cover pixel 
 */

function encodePixel(coverPixel, secretPixel) {
    // Get RGB values from both pixels
    var originalRed = coverPixel[RED];
    var originalGreen = coverPixel[GREEN];
    var originalBlue = coverPixel[BLUE];
    
    var secretRed = secretPixel[RED];
    var secretGreen = secretPixel[GREEN];
    var secretBlue = secretPixel[BLUE];
    
    // Determine what the red green and blue bits should be
    // for this pixel
    var redBit = 0;
    var greenBit = 0;
    var blueBit = 0;
    
    // Color values go from 0 to 255. 
    // If a value is in the lower half of the range, the bit should be 0. 
    // If a value is in the upper half of the range, the bit should be a 1.
    if(secretRed >= COLOR_THRESHOLD) {
        redBit = 1;
    }
    
    if (secretGreen >= COLOR_THRESHOLD) {
        greenBit = 1;
    }
    
    if (secretBlue >= COLOR_THRESHOLD) {
        blueBit = 1;
    }
    
    // Calculate new RGB values for the cover image
    // The lowest bit is set to the corresponding RGB value
    // for the secret image
    var newRed = setLowestBit(originalRed, redBit);
    var newGreen = setLowestBit(originalGreen, greenBit);
    var newBlue = setLowestBit(originalBlue, blueBit);
    
    // Update the cover pixel with the new RGB values
    coverPixel[RED] = newRed;
    coverPixel[GREEN] = newGreen;
    coverPixel[BLUE] = newBlue;
    
    // Return the modified cover pixel
    return coverPixel;
}

/* Extracts the RGB values for a secret pixel from the low bits
 * of the given cover pixel
 * Returns the resulting secret pixel 
 */

function decodePixel(coverPixel) {
    // Get the RGB values from the cover pixel
    var red = coverPixel[RED];
    var green = coverPixel[GREEN];
    var blue = coverPixel[BLUE];
    
    // Initialize a new secret pixel with 0s for R G and B
    var secretPixel = [MIN_COLOR_VALUE, MIN_COLOR_VALUE, MIN_COLOR_VALUE];
    
    // Calculate the RGB values for the secret pixel
    // Based on the lowest bit of each RGB value in the cover pixel!
    
    // Get the lowest bit from each RGB value in the cover pixel
    // If it is not even, the low bit is a 1
    // If it is even, the low bit is a 0
    var redBit = getLowestBit(red);
    var greenBit = getLowestBit(green);
    var blueBit = getLowestBit(blue);
    
    // If the redBit is a 1, max out the red value in the secret pixel
    // Otherwise the secret pixel gets no red
    if(redBit == 1) {
        secretPixel[RED] = MAX_COLOR_VALUE;
    } else {
        secretPixel[RED] = MIN_COLOR_VALUE;
    }
    
    // If the greenBit is a 1, max out the green value in the secret image
    // Otherwise the secret image gets no green in this pixel
    if(greenBit == 1) {
        secretPixel[GREEN] = MAX_COLOR_VALUE;
    } else {
        secretPixel[GREEN] = MIN_COLOR_VALUE;
    }
    
    // If the blueBit is a 1, max out the blue value in the secret image
    // Otherwise the secret image gets no blue in this pixel
    if(blueBit == 1) {
        secretPixel[BLUE] = MAX_COLOR_VALUE;
    } else {
        secretPixel[BLUE] = MIN_COLOR_VALUE;
    }
    
    // Return the calculated secret pixel
    return secretPixel;
}

//=========HELPER FUNCTIONS==========//

/* Returns true if the given value is even, otherwise returns false. */
function isEven(value) {
    return value % 2 == 0;
}


/* Given a number, return the lowest bit in the binary representation
 * of the number.
 * Returns either a 0 or a 1.
 */
function getLowestBit(value) {
    if(isEven(value)) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return 1;
    }
}


/* Given a number, return a new number with the same underlying bits
 * EXCEPT the lowest bit is set to the given bitValue.
 */
function setLowestBit(value, bitValue) {
    if(bitValue == 0) {
        // If value is even, the lowest bit is already 0.
        if(isEven(value)) {
            return value;
        } 
        // Otherwise, the lowest bit is 1. We subtract 1 to set it to 0.
        else {
            return value - 1;
        }
    }
    else {
        // If value is odd, the lowest bit is already 1
        if(!isEven(value)) {
            return value;
        }
        // Otherwise, the lowest bit is 0. We add 1 to set it to 1.
        else {
            return value + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please provide an explanation supporting the code you posted and explaining how it helps to solve the original answer.

Comment: Thank you for the formatting assistance. This final code that I added puts the entire code together to encode and then decode one image into another through steganography. The problem exists and this code here works to solve it within the "AP Computer Science Principles in Javascript" course in Unit #9 in CodeHS.